# Django transfer uploaded file

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to upload a file via django forms, then send it to an API.

Here's the encoding function:

```
#FYI, requestFile = request.FILES['file']
def EncodeFile(self, requestFile, fields = []):

    BOUNDARY    = '----------boundary------'
    CRLF        = '\r\n'
    body        = []
    # Add the metadata about the upload first

    for param in fields:
        body.extend(
          ['--' + BOUNDARY,
           'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="%s"' % param,
           '',
           fields[param],
           ])

    fileContent = requestFile.read()

    body.extend(
      ['--' + BOUNDARY,
       'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="%s"'
       % requestFile.name,
       # The upload server determines the mime-type, no need to set it.
       'Content-Type: ' + requestFile.content_type,
       '',
       fileContent,
       ])

    # Finalize the form body
    body.extend(['--' + BOUNDARY + '--', ''])
    result =  'multipart/form-data; boundary=%s' % BOUNDARY, CRLF.join(body)
    return result
```

The problem is that when it reaches "CRLF.join(body)" it complains about "'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte".

The exact same piece of code works flawlessly from the command line with the exception that the requestFile is actually a path to a file, and I'm doing an open(requestFile, 'rb') before reading the contents.

I can not for the life of me figure out what to do next. I've been googling for an answer for the past 10 hours or so.

Comment: Are you doing anything with the file stream before this function is called?  It sounds like the seek pointer isn't at the beginning of the stream. What happens if you do a `requestFile.seek(0)` at the top?

Comment: Not doing anything with the file prior to getting into this function.
Added requestFile.seek(0) as you've suggested. Same Error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently this line of code causes the problem:

```
'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="%s"' % requestFile.name,
```

The correct line would be instead:

```
'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="%s"' % smart_str(requestFile.name),
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to decode the data into a string and that fails on the join function. If django is using strict mode trying to decode the data it will throw an error. `ignore` mode will just skip those bytes, this might explain why it seems to work from the console).

So you don't want the response object to be converted to an unicode string. You should try to debug what function tries to convert it and try to prevent it. The join() function should not try to convert it to unicode.

To find the problem you can simplify it like this to help finding the root cause. This works for me in python shell (but it should cause same error in your case):

```
body = ["1", "\xff"]
result = 'multipart/form-data; boundary=%s' % BOUNDARY, CRLF.join(body)
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work either. I've tried smart_str, smart_unicode and force_unicode. None of them worked.

Comment: @CiprianTarta I modified answer to help you forward, you'll have to find what function tries to convert it to unicode.

Comment: If I'm doing a print fileContent before adding it to the body with the body.extend(..., fileContent) method, I'm seeing the binary data in the console. After this method is executed, the content gets encoded. This might be the problem, but how do I prevent it then? I've tried doing append instead of extend, even normal string concatenation.